# Eliminar elementos de un arreglo en php

Tags: php

Buen día

De acuerdo a una consulta en php, me genera el siguiente arreglo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Finca] => FINCA 1
            [0] => FINCA 1
            [Producto] => ALSTROEMERIA
            [1] => ALSTROEMERIA
            [year] => 2016
            [2] => 2016
            [week] => 26
            [3] => 26
            [quantity] => 91570
            [4] => 91570
            [quantity_origin] => 2096
            [5] => 2096
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Finca] => FINCA 2
            [0] => FINCA 2
            [Producto] => ALSTROEMERIA
            [1] => ALSTROEMERIA
            [year] => 2016
            [2] => 2016
            [week] => 26
            [3] => 26
            [quantity] => 65350
            [4] => 65350
            [quantity_origin] => 1444
            [5] => 1444
        )
)
```

Cómo hago para eliminar los índices que son numéricos, es decir que el arreglo quede de la siguiente manera:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Finca] => FINCA1
            [Producto] => ALSTROEMERIA
            [year] => 2016
            [week] => 26
            [quantity] => 91570
            [quantity_origin] => 2096
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Finca] => FINCA 2
            [Producto] => ALSTROEMERIA
            [year] => 2016
            [week] => 26
            [quantity] => 65350
            [quantity_origin] => 1444
        )
)
```

Lo hice con array_unique(), pero hay valores de los elementos 'quantity' y 'quantity_origin' que son iguales y con esta función me deja sólo el 'quantity'.

Muchas gracias, espero mi pregunta sea entendida.

Comment: Cuando hablas de consulta, es alguna consulta SQL? si es así, podrías prescindir de esos campos en la consulta?

Comment: Si es una consulta SQL y uso Phalcon para realizar la consulta

Comment: Y puedes prescindir de esos valores en el Select?. Y si pones la consulta sería de ayuda, ademas supongo que usaras ajax, para devolver valores o algo similar, si pones el código, también sería de ayuda

Comment: No del Select no, y si uso ajax para que me devuleva esos valores en un objeto!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con un loop foreach:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {      // Recorrer los elementos del array
    if (is_int($key)) {                 // Si la clave es un entero:
        unset($arr[$key]);              // Destruir la variable (elemento del array)
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Considerarias explicarle al *OP* lo que hace tu respuesta?

Comment: Muchas gracias por exponer tu respuesta!, me sirvió mucho Saludos!

Comment: De nada, espero que te sirva :))

Answer (score 0):

Originalmente puedes obtener directamente el arreglo sólo con las claves igual a los nombres de los camplos si utilizas:

```
$arreglo = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Para eliminar elementos de un arreglo utiliza [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-splice.php) en este caso podría ser:

```
foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
   if  (is_int( $key)  ) {
      array_splice( $data, $key, 1 );
   }
}
```

Comment: Hola, intente y funciona pero me deja los keys numericos y no los keys con los nombres, pero no conocía la función is_int() o me podrías explicar mejor? te agradecería, Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Para arreglos un-dimensionales. Esto garantiza que sean eliminados. Funciona para mi, saludos:

```
    while( count($arreglo) > 0 ) { 
        $arreglo = array_values($arreglo);          
        unset($arreglo[0]); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en la función que devolvió ese array. Esta usando un `$variabledelresultado->fetch_array()` y lo que necesitas es `$variabledelresultado->fetch_assoc()`

Esto te devolverá un array sin los indices numéricos, solo los asociativos.

Eliminarlos del array luego de cargados solo seria un desperdicio de memoria.