# Remover elementos de un arreglo y renombrar la clave de los elementos

Tags: php, php7

Tengo el siguiente arreglo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => amarillo
    [1] => azul
    [2] => rojo
    [3] => violeta
    [4] => verde
    [5] => naranja
    [6] => violeta
    [7] => negro
    [8] => azul
    [9] => amarillo
)
```

Cómo puedo hacer para buscar el elemento "violeta", eliminarlo y eliminar el anterior y posterior elemento a este, reorganizando nuevamente las claves para que queden numeradas desde cero. El resultado debería quedarme de la siguiente manera.

```
Array
(
    [0] => amarillo
    [1] => azul


    [2] => azul
    [3] => amarillo
)
```

Comment: Creo que esto te puede ayudar [Eliminar elementos de un arreglo en php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16644/eliminar-elementos-de-un-arreglo-en-php?rq=1).

Comment: si los remueves no los podras renombrar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo documentado de cómo podrías hacerlo, quizá haya respuestas más cortas, pero esta me funcionó

```
<?php
//Arreglo
$colores = array('amarillo',
'azul',
'rojo',
'violeta',
'verde',
'naranja',
'violeta',
'negro',
'azul',
'amarillo');

//Recorremos el arreglo
for( $i = 0; $i < count( $colores ); $i++ ) {
    //Buscamos el violeta
    if( $colores[ $i ] === 'violeta' ) {
        //Si existe entonces lo eliminamos
        unset( $colores[ $i ] );
        //Validamos si hay un elemento con un índice más arriba que el actual
        if( !empty( $colores[ $i + 1 ] ) ) {
            //Si existe entonces lo eliminamos
            unset( $colores[ $i + 1 ] );
        } 
        //Validamos si hay un elemento con un índice más abajo que el actual
        if( !empty( $colores[ $i - 1 ] ) ) {
            //Si existe entonces lo eliminamos
            unset( $colores[ $i - 1 ] );
        } 
    } 
}
//Reorganizamos el arreglo
$colores = array_values( $colores );

//Imprimimos resultado
print_r( $colores );

?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Tu solución me ayudó para lograr lo que necesitaba. El criterio de validar si existen fue muy bueno, no lo había considerado.

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar la función array_diff para eliminar el elemento con el valor "violeta"
la función te devolverá el arreglo actualizado, sin el elemento con el valor "violeta" le puedes pasar varios valores a eliminar

ejemplo:

```
$key=array_search('violeta', $my_array);
$arrDelete=array('violeta');
if($key>0)
  $arrDelete[]=$my_array[$key-1];
if($key<count($my_array)-1)
  $arrDelete[]=$my_array[$key+1];

$my_array = array_diff($my_array,  $arrDelete);
```

puedes revisar la documentación [Documentación oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff.php)

Comment: Creo que debí ser un poco más específico. La eliminación se debe hacer teniendo como referencia la palabra "violeta" y no el número de su clave. Luego de la eliminación de este elemento se debería eliminar el anterior y el posterior. Luego de la eliminación deberían renombrarse las claves para los elementos que quedan para que se numeren desde el cero otra vez.

Comment: @CarlosTerán actualice la respuesta para que aplique a tu requerimiento

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo con la funcion [array_splice](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-splice.php):

ejemplo:

```
 $arreglo = array("amarillo", //0
  "azul",  //  1
  "rojo",  // 2
  "violeta", //3 
  "verde", // 4
  "naranja",
  "chocolate",
  "negro",
  "azul");


 array_splice($arreglo,3,1); // eliminar el elemento violeta 3
print_r($arreglo);
```

resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => amarillo
    [1] => azul
    [2] => rojo
    [3] => verde
    [4] => naranja
    [5] => chocolate
    [6] => negro
    [7] => azul
)
```